# Bootstrap 3 Carousel flickering black

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm using a carousel to slide blocks of text. This works fine, however often a black flickering appears between the transitions. This is especially the case in Firefox and also when the screen is resized to smaller and after that maximized again. I posted a demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dr5zbj1m/

I'm using Bootstrap 3. Does anyone know a solution to this?

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="row row-carousel">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="well">
                      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod metus ipsum, non ullamcorper augue rutrum non. Donec id ante eleifend quam tristique pharetra.</p>
                      <p><br><img src="http://www.tanld.com/images/livedemo.png " class="img-responsive"></p>
                      <p class="text-center"><br><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Test</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item ">
                <div class="row row-carousel ">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="well ">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod metus ipsum, non ullamcorper augue rutrum non. Donec id ante eleifend quam tristique pharetra.</p>
                            <p>
                                <br>
                                <img src="http://www.tanld.com/images/livedemo.png " class="img-responsive">
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-center ">
                                <br><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " href="# ">Test</a>

                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row row-carousel">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="well ">
                      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod metus ipsum, non ullamcorper augue rutrum non. Donec id ante eleifend quam tristique pharetra.</p>
                      <p><br><img src="http://www.tanld.com/images/livedemo.png " class="img-responsive"></p>
                      <p class="text-center "><br><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="# ">Test</a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

.call-to-action {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
.row-carousel {
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 2px solid #786C8C;
    .col-md-12-carousel {
        text-align: center
    }
    .carousel {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .img-responsive {
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error in FireFox v.30.0 neither Chrome. Everything seems to work fine.

Comment: That's strange, I experience this issue on multiple desktop systems using Firefox 36.0.1. Have you tried to manually go back and forward between the slides using the carousel indicators?

Comment: Yes, I did it. I also tried to go back while the screen is resized to a smaller size. I couldn't see anything out of the ordinary behavior.

Comment: I guess it's a problem on my end then. Perhaps it's caused by my dual-monitor setup. Thanks for testing it!

Comment: You're welcome. Try to reproduce it on another computer with a single monitor setup and let us know the results.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the problem on a computer with a single monitor. Problem still only occurs in Firefox, after the jsfiddle-page has resized and maximized again. To illustrate the problem, I took a screenshot on the moment of slide transition: http://s23.postimg.org/klbmhyxrf/screen.png

Comment: @elton73: which version of FF?

Comment: @elton73: which version of FF?

Comment: @jbutler483: Firefox 36.0.1 (most recent version right now)

Comment: @elton73 I've updated my FF to 36.0.1 and after some tests (resizing, go back and forward between slides...etc) the carousel is working fine. Screenshot:  http://postimg.org/image/u4kt4dml3/

Comment: Thanks for testing. In that case I find the carousel suitable for a production environment, knowing that this is a rare issue.